# Operation returned an invalid status code 'MethodNotAllowed' - Bot Framework Emulator

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

I have design a bot with form flow model. When I am executing it locally in bot emulator. It's throwing a error.

> Exception: Operation returned an invalid status code ‘MethodNotAllowed’

```
"{ "message": "An error has occurred.", "exceptionMessage": "Operation returned an invalid status code 'MethodNotAllowed'", "exceptionType": "Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException", "stackTrace": " at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotState.<GetConversationDataWithHttpMessagesAsync>d__8.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.BotStateExtensions.<GetConversationDataAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ConnectorStore.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IBotDataStore<Microsoft-Bot-Connector-BotData>-LoadAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.CachingBotDataStore.<LoadFromInnerAndCache>d__8.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.CachingBotDataStore.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IBotDataStore<Microsoft-Bot-Connector-BotData>-LoadAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.BotDataBase`1.<LoadData>d__16.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.BotDataBase`1.<LoadAsync>d__8.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTaskManagerBotDataLoader.<LoadAsync>d__11.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ExceptionTranslationDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SerializeByConversation.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUser.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUser.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.LogPostToBot.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.<SendAsync>d__11.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.<SendAsync>d__6.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n at BookAFlight.MessagesController.<Post>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\\ITPlusPoint\\solomon.sarkar\\01 iCAT\\Projects\\Solomon\\ChatBots\\ITPlusPoint.Component\\BookAFlight\\Controllers\\MessagesController.cs:line 28\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()" }"
```

I am unable to run my currently developed bot neither the previous tested and running bots. 
Do I have problem with Bot Emulator? or any version mis-matching between BotFrameworks?

I am using VS 2015 and BotFramework V3. I have VS 2019 install in my computer as well. 
**ScreenShots (Run in BotEmulator)**
[image: The above screen shot has taken while executing the chatbot locally in Bot Emulator]

** Code for reference**

**MessageController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;using System.Threading.Tasks;using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using BookAFlight.Dialogs;
using BookAFlight.Models;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow;

namespace BookAFlight
{
    [BotAuthentication]
    public class MessagesController : ApiController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// POST: api/Messages
        /// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
        /// </summary>
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
        {
            if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => FlightBotDialog.dialog);
            }
            else
            {
                HandleSystemMessage(activity);
            }
            var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            return response;
            //if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            //{
            //    ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
            //    // calculate something for us to return
            //    int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

            //    // return our reply to the user
            //    Activity reply = activity.CreateReply($"You sent {activity.Text} which was {length} characters");
            //    await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    HandleSystemMessage(activity);
            //}
            //var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            //return response;
        }
        internal static IDialog<EnquiryForm> MakeRootDialog()
        {
            return Chain.From(() => FormDialog.FromForm(EnquiryForm.BuildForm));
        }
        private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
        {
            if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
            {
                // Implement user deletion here
                // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
            {
                // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
                // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
                // Not available in all channels
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
            {
                // Handle add/remove from contact lists
                // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
            {
                // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
            }
            else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
            {
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**FlightBotDialog.cs**

```
using BookAFlight.Models;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.FormFlow;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BookAFlight.Dialogs
{
    public class FlightBotDialog
    {
        public static readonly IDialog<string> dialog = Chain.PostToChain()
           .Select(msg => msg.Text)
           .Switch(
           new RegexCase<IDialog<string>>(new Regex("^hi", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase), (context, text) =>
           {
               return Chain.ContinueWith(new MyDialog(), AfterMyDialogContinue);
           }),
           new DefaultCase<string, IDialog<string>>((context, text) =>
           {
               return Chain.ContinueWith(FormDialog.FromForm(EnquiryForm.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart), AfterMyDialogContinue);
           }))
           .Unwrap()
           .PostToUser();

        private async static Task<IDialog<string>> AfterMyDialogContinue(IBotContext context, IAwaitable<object> item)
        {
            var token = await item;
            var name = "User";
            context.UserData.TryGetValue<string>("Name", out name);
            return Chain.Return($"Thanks. Please type something-");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the code which throws exception?

Comment: Hi @AlexanderGoldabin I have added the sample code by editing the question, Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long research on comment given by @Alexander, I have found this blog [Bot State Service will soon be retired on March 31st, 2018](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/12/19/bot-state-service-will-soon-retired-march-31st-2018/). after gone through the content I found we need to store the state in database or in Local Memory. So I have added a code in **Global.asax** file, which resolve my issue.

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Conversation.UpdateContainer(
        builder =>
        {
            builder.RegisterModule(new AzureModule(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
            // Bot Storage: register state storage for your bot
            // Default store: volatile in-memory store - Only for prototyping!
            // var store = new InMemoryDataStore();
            // This sample will use Azure Table Storage 
            //var store = new TableBotDataStore(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            var store = new InMemoryDataStore();
            builder.Register(c => store)
                .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
                .AsSelf()
                .SingleInstance();
        });

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`MethodNotAllowed` error code means that you are using wrong HTTP method, e.g. calling endpoint with POST, when it allows only GET or DELETE

Comment: Thank you for your response @Alexander, But the same code was working fine earlier.

I am executing it locally in BotEmulator, not yet hosted in azure.

Comment: Yes!,The end point is http://localhost:3979/api/messages

I am executing it locally in BotEmulator, not yet hosted in azure

Comment: You could have added another method by this route `/api/messages` for example. It's hard to say exactly what have changed without code, both calling HTTP request and API endpoint.